# Example of a set with some caracteristics.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-writing

My question this time is, I am asked to find an example of a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that it is closed but not bounded, and all continous function defined there are also uniform continous, but is difficult for me to think of some example (I thought in intervals of the form [k, $\infty$) but I don't know if it works), well I don't know how to proceed, and another thing, once you have the subset how do you prove that every function there is also uniform continous, I can't figure out that, Can you help me please?

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: Well,if you want to be lazy or you're pressed for time, R^n itself works nicely...........lol

Comment: really?, I dont think so, can you prove it :), thanks for the help :) anyway

Comment: Uh,any space under a topology is both open and closed by definition,so R*n is closed. But it's clearly unbounded since R^n = (-∞,+∞).Of course,that doesn't answer the second part of your question,which is trickier,does it?

Comment: right but the uniform condition, and wel I dont know topology :)

Comment: Learn it,it'll make your life so much easier in analysis..........

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice :)

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following subset of $R^{n}$ with usual topology i.e. the usual Euclidean distance function:The set S of all vectors in $R^{n}$ with integer components only. Each component of each vector will be an integer, which lies between any 2 real numbers.which are components of vectors in $R^{n}$. Each integer component is a singleton on the real line and therefore a closed set. S is the Cartesian product of all these singletons which is a subset of the n-Cartesian product of the real line.Therefore,every such vector in S is a closed subset of $R^{n}$. We then take the intersection of all open balls in $R^{n}$ containing such a vector,which clearly will be equal to S by definition. Since S is an infinite intersection of closed sets,S is closed in $R^{n}$. But it is clearly unbounded since it contains n-Cartesian products of Z and this set is countably infinite and therefore unbounded.

You can try the second part yourself,I don't have time......lol

Comment: thanks a lot , but do I need topology for the second part ?

Comment: No,you should be able to do that using the methods of calculus/classical analysis only.

Comment: good, and with this is covered the uniform continuity part ?

Comment: It should do it,yes.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot, and can I write it like above or I need something else ?